# Parsing a Python expression without evaluation

Tags: python, parsing

I have an app written in Electron/Typescript and I need to validate that a user input is a valid Python expression.

For example:

1. `cos(PARAMPOLY.engineeringValue1) + cos(PARAMPOLY.engineeringValue2)`
2. `x + y + z`

I have no way of producing the correct type and value of the operands for these expressions. I need something which parses the expression and tells me if there is an expression error.

The Python `eval()` function parses and evaluates the expression. I need only a parsing.

Is there something for that need?

Answer (score 3):

You may want *full compilation* into a full Python code object, or you can just parse into an abstract syntax tree. You can use the [`compile()` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#compile) to achieve either, or just use [`ast.parse()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.parse) to produce the tree.

Parsing into an AST tokenizes the input and outputs a tree of syntax objects that you can then further analyse or transform. Compiling into bytecode goes one step further, using that AST to create a Python code object that you can optionally execute with either `eval()` or the [`exec()` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#exec); note that the latter always returns `None` and is probably not the best choice to evaluate an expression code object.

`eval(string)` uses `eval(compile(string, "<stdin>", "eval"))` to compile a string argument to a code object, then execute it, so `compile(string, "<stdin>", "eval")` would give you the same result without execution.

Use `"eval"` as the mode if only an *expression* is valid, or `"exec"` if full Python *statements* are to be accepted. `compile()` (and `ast.parse()`) raises a  `SyntaxError` exception if the input is not a valid Python expression (`"eval"`) or not valid statements (`"exec"`).

Demo:

```
>>> example1 = "cos(PARAMPOLY.engineeringValue1) + cos(PARAMPOLY.engineeringValue2)"
>>> example2 = "x + y + z"
>>> compile(example1, "<stdin>", "eval")
<code object <module> at 0x111c2eae0, file "<stdin>", line 1>
>>> compile(example2, "<stdin>", "eval")
<code object <module> at 0x111c2e540, file "<stdin>", line 1>
>>> result2 = _
>>> eval(result2, {"x": 42, "y": 81, "z": 117})
240
>>> compile("not a valid expression", "<stdin>", "eval")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    not a valid expression
              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Parsing to an AST would let you discover what names the code expects to be able to access; you can collect names by looking for `Name` nodes:

```
>>> import ast
>>> tree1 = ast.parse(example1)
>>> tree2 = ast.parse(example2)
>>> ast.dump(tree2.body[0])
"Expr(value=BinOp(left=Call(func=Name(id='cos', ctx=Load()), args=[Attribute(value=Name(id='PARAMPOLY', ctx=Load()), attr='engineeringValue1', ctx=Load())], keywords=[]), op=Add(), right=Call(func=Name(id='cos', ctx=Load()), args=[Attribute(value=Name(id='PARAMPOLY', ctx=Load()), attr='engineeringValue2', ctx=Load())], keywords=[])))"
>>> ast.dump(tree2.body[0])
"Expr(value=BinOp(left=BinOp(left=Name(id='x', ctx=Load()), op=Add(), right=Name(id='y', ctx=Load())), op=Add(), right=Name(id='z', ctx=Load())))"
>>> {node.id for node in ast.walk(tree1) if isinstance(node, ast.Name)}
{'cos', 'PARAMPOLY'}
>>> {node.id for node in ast.walk(tree2) if isinstance(node, ast.Name)}
{'x', 'z', 'y'}
```

Note that the above ignored context, so the `PARAMPONLY` attribute name is listed too. Write a [`ast.NodeVisitor` subclass](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.NodeVisitor) if you need to process a syntax tree with more context.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your explanation.

To go further, imagine I expect math vocabulary items like "cos" and "sin" in the expression provided by the user and I want to check it.

ex : 
1 - IN : cos(a) + sin(b) OUT : OK
2 - IN : cos(a,b) OUT NOK
3 - IN fake(a) OUT NOK
4 - IN tan(a) OUT NOK


As I undertand, parsing is not enough, I need to use eval expression but I don't 
know how to manage operand.

`from math import *
print(eval('cos(a) + sin(b)', {'cos': cos, 'sin': sin})) `
  

Do you have any idea ?

Comment: @Julieng31: if you need to evaluate mathematical expressions, then see [Evaluating a mathematical expression in a string](//stackoverflow.com/q/2371436), where one of the answers led to https://github.com/danthedeckie/simpleeval, which is, at the very least, a starting point for what you want to do. The latter uses the AST to then drive expression execution in a safe and controlled way.

Comment: @Julieng31: at any rate, something like `cos(a b)` would be parsed into a `Call()` expression, with `cos` as the name of the callable, with two arguments. You can then use something like the [function signature](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html#inspect.signature) or information you stored up front to see if that call could work at all (`len(inspect.signature(math.cos).parameters)` is `1`, so no, that call would fail).